# Hiding Axis Label SSRS Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am creating a chart in SSRS.  Along the x-axis, I have two groupings.  I want to hide the second grouping because it makes teh bottom of my graph look messy, but I need to keep the group.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the x-axis labels but that would hide both groups. I think if you select the group and set the Category Group Properties dialog Label's expression to  " " or "" then it will not show. You can mess with the offset if space is still being used.